# Distinct without group by/having/distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, distinct

I am trying to find an appropriate solution to the following problem:
I have an activity-tracking database and I want to get the status at a specific date (ex: 11-Sept)

| Activity | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Done | 12-Sept |
| 100 | In prog | 10-Sept |
| 110 | In prog | 12-Sept |
| 110 | In prog | 09-Sept |
| 110 | New | 08-Sept |

My current query is: select * from table where Date <= 11-Sept
My current output is:

| Activity | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | In prog | 10-Sept |
| 110 | In prog | 09-Sept |
| 110 | New | 08-Sept |

Problem is I want to limit to only 1 row (newest date) for each activity code.
Desired output is:

| Activity | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | In prog | 10-Sept |
| 110 | In prog | 09-Sept |

BUT...

I can't user group by, having or distinct, so the following solutions are not acceptable:

```
select distinct Name
from table
where Date <= 11-Sept

select name, max(date)
from table 
where Date <= 11-Sept
group by name
```

**Basically.. I can only use the where clause**

Anyone has an idea?

Desired output is:

| Activity | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | In prog | 10-Sept |
| 110 | In prog | 09-Sept |

To be mentioned: the format of the date here is simplified

Comment: Row number.....

Comment: `11-Sept` is a string, not a date and can't be sorted in date order. What does `Date` actually contain?

Comment: I assume your date format is just your shorthand because if that's what you data looks like you are in trouble.

Comment: Correct, the date format is just simplified here

Comment: If you can only use the `WHERE` clause you need to show us the **exact** query that this will slot into. Not just some approximation to it. As it will need to be a sub query correlated to the outer query that you have not shown us

Comment: @charlieface the dup doesn't actually appear to have the not exists solution.

Comment: @DaleK True, you are welcome to add it though. There are some other triangular join answers though, eg `SELECT Activity, Status, Date FROM yourTable t1 WHERE t1.Date <= '20230911' AND Date IN (SELECT TOP (1) t2.Date FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.Date <= '20230911' AND t2.Activity = t1.Activity ORDER BY t2.Date DESC)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One canonical way to do this uses the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Activity ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Date < '20230911'
)

SELECT Activity, Status, Date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Activity;
```

Another more concise (yet less performant) way:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Activity, Status, Date
FROM yourTable
WHERE Date <= '20230911'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Activity ORDER BY Date DESC);
```

A third option, using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT Activity, Status, Date
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    Date <= '20230911' AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM yourTable t2
        WHERE t2.Date <= '20230911' AND
              t2.Activity = t1.Activity AND
              t2.Date > t1.Date
    )
ORDER BY Activity;
```

Comment: I cannot use cte and I cannot use top 1. I need a different solution. I can edit only the where clause of the SQL statement

Comment: Please explain where these limitations come from

Comment: The query passes through an application, that allows me to edit only the where-clause.

Comment: You need to put that sort of information in your question from the start

Comment: @DaleK no, it's much more fun to create new roadblocks so people can waste time on solutions that don't work

Comment: Thank you, third option from here works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```sql
select *
into #data
from 
(
    VALUES  (100, N'Done', N'20230912')
    ,   (100, N'In prog', N'20230910')
    ,   (110, N'In prog', N'20230912')
    ,   (110, N'In prog', N'20230909')
    ,   (110, N'New', N'20230908')
) t (Activity,Status,Date)

select *
from #data d
where date <= '20230911'
and not exists(
    select 1
    from  #data d2
    where d2.Activity = d.activity
    and d2.date > d.date
    and d2.date <= '20230911'
    )
```

This allows to get the top date where there are no dates above it

Answer (score -2):

You can use `subquery` to filter the rows with the latest date for each activity code.

```
SELECT t1.Activity, t1.Status, t1.Date
FROM YourTable t1
WHERE t1.Date <= '2023-09-11'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM YourTable t2
    WHERE t2.Activity = t1.Activity
    AND t2.Date > t1.Date
    AND t2.Date <= '2023-09-11'
);
```

Comment: That's identical to an existing answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;

CREATE TABLE #t
(
Activity INT         NOT NULL,
Status   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Date     DATE        NOT NULL
)
;

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES
(100, 'Done'   , '2023-09-12'),
(100, 'In prog', '2023-09-10'),
(110, 'In prog', '2023-09-12'),
(110, 'In prog', '2023-09-09'),
(110, 'New'    , '2023-09-08')
;

SELECT *
FROM #t AS t
WHERE DATE <= '2023-09-11'
AND NOT EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM  #t AS t2
WHERE t2.Activity = t.activity
AND t2.date > t.date
AND t2.date <= '2023-09-11'
)
```

Comment: That's identical to existing answers

Comment: Wow, the fourth answer with the same query ;)